# Is there a way to gain such an estimate?

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, inequalities, harmonic-analysis, diophantine-approximation

This problem could be viewed as a polynomial generalization of the Lonely runner conjecture. And $p$, $n$ are taken sufficiently large. Take $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ fixed, $A_p \subset (\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is a finite set, and put $|A_p|=n$. $f=\sum_{i=0}^d a_ix^i\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a polynomial $a_0=0$, assume that it satisfies property $P_f$ for $p\in\Bbb N^\ast$, i.e.
$$\newcommand{\degr}{\operatorname{deg}}
f(x)\neq f(y) \quad \forall x\neq y,\;x,y\in \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z},
$$
So prime $p$ has property $P_f$ is just saying that $f$ is not ramified over $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$. Put $\degr(f)=d\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and finally consider
$$C_{p}(n,d)=\frac{\min_{\substack{f\in \mathbb{Z}[X],f=\sum_{i=0}^d a_ix^i,\ a_0=0,\\\degr(f)=d\in \mathbb{N}^*}} \max
_{t\in \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}}\min_{a,b\in A_p}\|f(ta)-f(tb)\|}{p}.\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$C(n,d)=\liminf_{\substack{p \text{ prime,} \\ p\text{ satisfies  property $P_f$ for $f$}}} C_{p}(n,d).\label{2}\tag{2}$$
We can prove a trivial estimate on \eqref{2} by using a "volume" counting argument, i.e.
$$C(n,d)\geq \frac{1}{2n}$$
**Question**: in general, can we improve the constant $2$, i.e. does there exist a constant $b(n,d)<2$, such that
$$
C(n,d)\geq \frac{1}{b(n,d)n}\quad?
$$

Comment: If $p$ is fixed, then tou cannot take the limit over $p$. Otherwise, $C$ cannot depend on $p$. So something went wrong...

Comment: I do not make $p$ fixed, I let $p$ run on the set such that $f$ is not ramified over $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So, to say it again, how can the bound for $C$ depend on $p$ when you take the *limit* over $p$?

Comment: @ Ilya Bogdanov, corrected, thanks.